# Bounded operator on dense subspaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Give an operator like this or show it doesn't exist: Operator $T: X\rightarrow Y$ is bijective. $X,Y$ are dense subspaces of a Banach space $Z$, and $X$ is proper subset of $Y$. Both $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are bounded.

Comment: I have an idea as the following: By using the denseness of $X$, we can extend $T$ to be $T_1: Y\rightarrow Y_1$, $T_1$ is bijective and $T_1,T$ have the same bound. Also we can show $Y$ is proper subset of $Y_1$. Then we keep doing like this and get a sequence of operators: $T_1: Y\rightarrow Y_1$, $T_2: Y\rightarrow Y_2$, $\ldots$ However, the question is can we get $Y_n=Z$ through finite steps? If so, the operator $TT_1\ldots T_n: X\rightarrow Z$ is bounded. Since $Z$ is complete, $X$ is complete, a contradiction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linear bijection between a normed vector space and its proper subspace](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390476/linear-bijection-between-a-normed-vector-space-and-its-proper-subspace)

Comment: No. I didn't duplicate it from anyone else. If you make a statement, please show your proof.

Comment: I've read the answer of Linear bijection between a normed vector space and its proper subspace – Norbert, but it's not complete.

Comment: In this context, "duplicate" isn't an accusation of copying without reference.  It's an automatically generated message informing that the user (Norbert in this case) thought the question is equivalent to (or contained within) an earlier question, and has voted to close for this reason.